# How to terminate execution of a fish script from a sourced file?

Tags: shell, fish

The `exit` command when executed from a file being sourced doesn't terminate the execution of the program where it was being sourced, how to do this? Consider this files for a clearer explanation:

a.fish:

```
source b.fish
echo "This should never run!"
```

b.fish:

```
echo "Failing now"
exit 1
```

This will result in this (undesired output):

```
Failing now
This should never run!
```

And the exit status is 0! Is there a solution for B to terminate execution of A as if `exit` was written in A itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly working the way you want with `bash` and `zsh`. Still, I found a solution for `fish`:

```
source b.fish; or exit 1
```

This will exit `a.fish` if `b.fish` exited with `exit 1`, and will continue otherwise.

Comment: hadn't thought of it, perfect. To repeat the exit code, you could change `exit 1` for `exit $status`